# non uniform spacing, multivariate derivative with numpy.gradient

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

so I'm trying to get the second derivative of the following formula using numpy.gradient, and I'm trying to differentiate it once by S[:,0] and then by S[:,1]

```
S = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, covariance, N)
formula = (S[:,0]**2) * (S[:,1]**2)
```

But the thing is when I use spacings as the second argument of numpy.gradient

```
dx = np.diff(S[:,0])
dy = np.diff(S[:,1])
dfdx = np.gradient(formula,dx)
```

I get the error saying

```
ValueError: when 1d, distances must match the length of the corresponding dimension
```

And I get that's because the spacings vector length is one element less than the formula's, but I didn't know what to do to fix that.
I've read somewhere also that you can have coordinates of the point rather than the spacing as the second argument, but when I tried checking the result out of that by differentiating the formula by S[:,0] and then by S[:,1], and then trying to differentiate it this time by S[:,0] and then by S[:,1], and comparing the two results, which should be similar; there was a huge difference between those two results.

Can anybody explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

When introducing the vector of coordinates of values of your function using Numpy's `gradient`, you have to be careful to either introduce it as a list with as many arrays as dimensions of your function, or to specify at which axis (as an argument of `gradient`) you want to calculate the gradient.
When you checked both ways of differentiation, I think the problem is that your formula isn't actually two-dimensional, but one-dimensional (even though you use data from two variables, note your `f` array has only one dimension).

Take a look at this little script in which we verify that, indeed, the order of differentiation doesn't alter the result (assuming your function is well-behaved).

```
import numpy as np
# Dummy arrays and function 
x = np.linspace(0,1,50)
y = np.linspace(0,2,50)
f = np.sin(2*np.pi*x[:,None]) * np.cos(2*np.pi*y)

dfdx  = np.gradient(f, x, axis = 0)
df2dy = np.gradient(dfdx, y, axis = 1)

dfdy  = np.gradient(f, y, axis = 1)
df2dx = np.gradient(dfdy, x, axis = 0)

# Check how many values are essentially different
print(np.sum(~np.isclose(df2dx, df2dy)))
```

Does this apply to your problem?